# watchOS 5 error adding image to “Graphic complication": the image rep xxx is not aplicable to this complication

Tags: watchos, xcode10

I’m using Xcode 10 and watchos 5.

I have added to my watchOS app the app icon to all the “clasical complications” in Apple Watch app (alfa channel and ony one color in diferent sizes) and it works perfect.

When I try to add the icon for the new “graphic complications” that could be “full color” images this erro is show:

[watchos 5 graphic complication image upload error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO7HX.png)

In the “other” complications if you upload a wrong file (p.e. size) the error give information about it, but in this case it seems that the file uploaded “is not compatible”.

After reading the documentation I understand that this images can be “full color” and png format (with the all the available sizes), I have tried a lot of combinations and always get the same error.

Any idea about what could be happen?
Has anyone add this kind of “graphic complication”?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Maybe if you show an image of the tree.  The name and structure of the assets seems to matter some times.  I have added a graphic circular complication to an existing watch app and it was able to load the complication image.  Did you figure it out yet?

Comment: Finally it was a problem with the structure ;) thaks

Comment: Same problem here - can you elaborate a bit what kind of structure problem that was?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you discover a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use ***.pdf*** image instead **.png**

Comment: This worked for me when adding a Graphic Corner image. Oddly, this was the only image with this problem in an app with all Complication families

Comment: Weird but it works. Why do I have to come here to find that out? Fixed the yellow warning I was getting for all my "Graphic ..." type complication images.